# Abelian varieties over an algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

We know that an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ is a torus, and I've read that an abelian surface over $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda \cong \mathbb{Z}^4$. So I suppose that an abelian variety of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2n}$.

**Question 1.** I wonder to what extent is the above true over the algebraic closure of a number field $k$? For example, is an elliptic curve over $\bar{k}$ isomorphic to a torus over $\bar{k}$?

**Question 2.** In algebraic geometry we also have the definition of a torus to be a product of multiplicative groups $\mathbb{G}_m$. For an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$, would it then be isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_m^n$ for some $n$? If so, how do we determine $n$?

Comment: I believe that you’re confusing *topological* tori (isomorphic to products of circles, compact) and *algebraic* tori (isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$, very non-compact).

Comment: @Aphelli Ok I see, so the usual elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ would obviously be the product of $S^1$. What about an elliptic curve over an alg. closure of a number field? Do we get something close to a torus? I know for sure it can be embedded in the usual product of circles since $\bar{k} \subset \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: An abelian variety (over any base field) is *proper*: its analytification is compact. This is not the case for *algebraic* tori at all (ex: elliptic curves have no non-constant global functions – tori have many). Naturally, an abelian variety over a number field embeds into a product of circles, but the topology to be considered isn’t clear at all.